# How to attach data- properties to table headers in jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm creating a datatable using the following code:

```
  var oTable = $table.dataTable({
    'deferRender': true,
    'dom': 'rtS',
    'scrollX': '100%',
    'scrollY': $('#content').height() + 'px',
    'serverSide': true,
    'processing': true,
    'ajax': getData,
    'order': [],
    'columns': header
  });
```

The header variable has the following form:

```
var header = [
  { 'title': 'some title', 'orderable': false, 'className': 'myclass' },
  // ...
];
```

and `getData()` provides the content for the table.

Now I want to assign certain `data-` properties to the table headers to be used with my contextmenu, but can't find any mentioning in the documentation, how to do so.

I just found the `className` property for the column definition, which allows me to add some classes to the cells. However, this will add the class to *all* cells of that column and not just the header. Furthermore, it is just a class and not a `data-` property.

**Is there any way (without using the render/init callbacks) to attach custom properties to the header cells of a datatable?**

Comment: Not as dedicated builtin functions in dataTables, to my knowledge. But is standard attribute assigment not adequate for you, like `$("#example th:eq(0)").attr('data-example', 'example');` etc? example -> http://jsfiddle.net/zwmmn0tz/

Comment: @davidkonrad That is basically the approach i was referring to with the callbacks. I would prefer some built in mechanism.

Comment: I thought you meant _without_ callbacks :) There is always [**headerCallback**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/headerCallback) / [**fnHeaderCallback**](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnHeaderCallback)

Comment: The general approach is something like: "wait for the rendering to finish", "select the table headers" and then "attach the data". Problem here would be that I would have again to match the header cells to my source header data ...